# How can I replace a value from one array with a value in the same index of another array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 3D numpy arrays which represent two images. The shape of each array is (1080, 1920, 3). The number 3 represents the RGB value of each pixel in the image.

My goal is to replace every non-black pixel in the first array to the value of the "parallel" pixel (in the same index) from the other array.

How can I do this using only numpy methods?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Could you add a small input sample and the expected output?

Comment: 2 steps: 1. Create a (1080*1920) boolean mask with black pixel from first image as false. 2. Map the boolean mask to the second image array. Look up `np.ma` methods.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you add a little code please? I don't understand what to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a mask with True/False values

```
# All pixels should be normalized 0..1 or 0..254
first_img = np.random.rand(1920,1080,3)
second_img = np.random.rand(1920,1080,3)

eps = 0.01  # Black pixel threshold
mask = first_img.sum(axis=2) > eps

for i in range(first_img.shape[2]):
    first_img[:,:,i] = (first_img[:, :, i] * mask) + ((1 - mask) * second_img[:, :, i])
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed reply but your code replacing the black pixels instead of the non-black pixels :) What do i need to change in order to let this work properly?

Comment: Just replace `mask = first_img.sum(axis=2) > eps` with `mask = first_img.sum(axis=2) < eps`